# MySQL query to show combinations of output

Tags: mysql

I have to write a mysql query to find total sales on particular days. I am able to find it, but unable to show combined results.

The table looks like:

```
Date, Order_id, Product_id, Quantity
'01-JUL-11',O1,P1,5
'01-JUL-11',O2,P2,2
'01-JUL-11',O3,P3,10
'01-JUL-11',O4,P1,10
'02-JUL-11',O5,P3,5
'02-JUL-11',O6,P4,6
'02-JUL-11',O7,P1,2
'02-JUL-11',O8,P5,1
'02-JUL-11',O9,P6,2
'02-JUL-11',O10,P2,4
```

Desired Output:

```
Product_id Total Sales on Day '02-JUL-11' Total Sales on Day '02-JUL-11'
P1 15 2
P2 2 4
P3 10 5
P4 0 6
P5 0 1
P6 0 2
```

What I have tried is:

```
Select distinct product_id
from orders;
```

Output:

```
P1
P2
P3
P4
P5
P6

Select product_id, sum(quantity) from orders
where order_day = '11-07-01'
group by product_id
```

OUTPUT:

```
P1 15
P2 2
P3 10


Select product_id, sum(quantity) from orders
where order_day = '11-07-02'
group by product_id
```

OUTPUT:

```
P1 2
P2 4
P3 5
P4 6
P5 1
P6 2
```

This gives me the desired result but I want to somehow combine the columns.

Query that worked for me: (However puts null for 0)

```
Select X.product_id, X.s, Y.t from 
(SELECT A.product_id as product_id, B.s as s FROM 
(Select distinct product_id
from orders) A
LEFT JOIN
(Select product_id, sum(quantity) as s from orders
where order_day = '11-07-01'
group by product_id) B
ON A.product_id = B.product_id) X
Left join
(Select product_id, sum(quantity) as t from orders
where order_day = '11-07-02'
group by product_id) Y
on X.product_id = Y.product_id;
```

Comment: Your sample input and output doesn't add up, but I _think_ you might be able to get away with a simple pivot query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only two days summarized in your report, then a simple (non dynamic) pivot query should do the trick:

```
SELECT product_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN order_day = '11-07-01' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS `Total Sales on Day '01-JUL-11'`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN order_day = '11-07-02' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS `Total Sales on Day '02-JUL-11'`
FROM orders
WHERE order_day = '11-07-01' OR order_day = '11-07-02'
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Can you explain this subquery: SUM(CASE WHEN order_day = '11-07-01' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END)

Comment: @Parin This will sum the `quantity` _only_ for a particular day, otherwise it takes 0.  And this will be applied to every record in the subselect.

Comment: Thanks, its readable but I wanted to know how you came about this query.
If I had known about this syntax, possibly i could've written this code. I have an interview with amazon soon, can you suggest some study material that will enrich me with such knowledge. (I have solved hackkerrank and leetcode)

Comment: Amazon is a tough interview (I have done it).  Just Google "pivot query" and you will get results.  Another good interview question is SQL gaps and islands.  Also check out the Tech on the Net website which covers SQL well.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation is the way to go.  But you should learn to use proper date formats.  The ISO/ANSI standard is YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD:

```
Select product_id,
      sum(case when order_day = '2011-07-01' then quantity else 0 end) as q_20110701,     
      sum(case when order_day = '2011-07-02' then quantity else 0 end) as q_20110702
from orders o
where order_day in ('2011-07-01', '2011-07-02')
group by product_id;
```

An alternative, if you can live with separate rows for each day, is:

```
Select product_id, order_day, sum(quantity)
from orders
where order_day in ('2011-07-01', '2011-07-02')
group by product_id, order_day,
```

Comment: sum(case when order_day = '2011-07-01' then quantity else 0 end) 
Can you explain this?

Comment: That is conditional aggregation.  It adds sums the `quantity` whenever the date is the specified date.